# KML to SHP - Script error 000840: The value is not a feature layer when I add FeatureClasstoShapefile tool to script

Tags: python, shapefile, kml, feature-layer

I want to do is to convert KML files to shapefiles and I haven't seem to be able to find a straight forward script anywhere. Eventually, I would like to turn this into a script tool to use personally, but right now I just want to the code to work.

I've copied almost exactly what ESRI has on their website for the KMLtoLayer tool (with a few tweeks) and then I added the FeatureClasstoShapefile tool to convert the feature classes within the final gdb from the KMLtoLayer tool to shapefiles in a separate folder.

I've ran the script for each tool separately and they work fine, but once I combine them, the FeatureClasstoShapefile tool seems to fail with the error

> 000840: the value is not a Feature Layer.

I don't understand why it would work on its own but not in the full script. Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import os
import arcpy

# Set workspace (where all the KMLs are)
arcpy.env.workspace = "Path to root folder" # This is normally populated, removed for the post
root_folder = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set local variables and location for the consolidated file geodatabase
# Create a new folder to save file geodatabases
out_location = os.path.join(root_folder, 'fgdbs') ## Name of new folder
if not os.path.exists(out_location):
    os.makedirs(out_location)
    print("New folder created")
gdb = 'AllKMLLayers.gdb'
gdb_location = os.path.join(out_location, gdb)

# Create the master FileGeodatabase
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_location, gdb)

# Convert all KMZ and KML files found in the current workspace
for kml in arcpy.ListFiles('*.KM*'):
    print("CONVERTING: {0}".format(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, kml)))
    kmlFile = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, kml)
    arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(kmlFile, out_location)

# Change the workspace to fGDB location
arcpy.env.workspace = out_location

# Loop through all the FileGeodatabases within the workspace
wks = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*', 'FileGDB')
# Skip the Master GDB
wks.remove(gdb_location)

for fgdb in wks:  
    # Change the workspace to the current FileGeodatabase
    arcpy.env.workspace = fgdb

    # For every Featureclass inside, copy it to the Master and use the name 
    # from the original fGDB  
    feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*', '', 'Placemarks')
    for fc in feature_classes:
        print("COPYING: {} FROM: {}".format(fc, fgdb))
        fcCopy = os.path.join(fgdb, 'Placemarks', fc)
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
            fcCopy, gdb_location, fgdb[fgdb.rfind(os.sep) + 1:-4])


# Set the workspace to the file geodatabase containing the feature classes        
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb_location
out_path = root_folder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for featureclass in fcs:
    # Specify output shapefile name including .shp extension
    output_shp = os.path.join(out_path, featureclass + ".shp")
    
    print(f"COPYING: {featureclass} FROM: {gdb_location}")

    try:
        # Convert the feature class to a shapefile directly
        arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(featureclass, out_path)
        print(f"Converted {featureclass} to shapefile at: {output_shp}")
    
    except arcpy.ExecuteError as e:
        print(f"ERROR: {str(e)}")
```